# What's the best way to store 2 x n Strings in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, multidimensional-array

I would like to store a different count of String data pairs in this format:

```
string a[n][2]{ 
{"1","2"},
{"3","4"},
{"5","6"}
{... }};
```

I would like to add a new pair by using the append methode or something similar... But is that possible and nice to handle with a 2D array or should I use a dictionaire?? And how could I implement that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially use an array of tuples to solve this:

```
typealias StringPair = (String, String)

var myStrings = [StringPair]()

myStrings.append(StringPair("1", "2"))
```

Edit: To search for a string pair, you could do:

```
var doesItContain1 = myStrings.contains {
    $0.0 == "1"
}
```

You could also change your type alias to use names:

```
typealias StringPair = (string1: String, string2: String)
```

And then filter with:

```
var doesItContain1 = myStrings.contains {
    $0.string1 == "1"
}
```

Edit 2: To sort:

```
var sorted = myStrings.sort {
    return $0.string1 < $1.string1
}
```

Comment: That's what I searched for! Thanks :)

Comment: What is the best way to search for a specific string pair? I tried                    if( !myStrings.contains(AnyObject,UUID)) Something like that but it doesn't work... I only have to proof the second value, so what do I have to do in this case :)

Comment: Nice! and one last question is how can I sort this array? sorry I'm not so familiar with swift...